# Mpdf cannot use Custom Fonts in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, mpdf

i want to implement two custom fonts to my pdf document in my cakephp application. i use the documentation but the default font alway draw.

i tried to implement it over the cakepdf options field. this run the constructor of mpdf and i know the paths of the files are correct but nothing changed

```php
$defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];
$fontDirs = array_merge($fontDirs, [
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/webroot/font/Montserrat',
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/webroot/font/Poppins',
]);

$defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];
$fontData = $fontData + [
    'Montserrat' => [
        'R' => 'Montserrat-Regular.ttf'
    ],
    'Poppins' => [
        'R' => 'Poppins-Regular.ttf'
    ]
];

Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => [
        'className' => 'CakePdf.Mpdf',
        'options' => [
            'fontDir' => $fontDirs,
            'fontdata' => $fontData,
            'default_font_size' => 20,
            'default_font' => 'Montserrat'
        ]
    ],
    'margin' => [
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ],
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'download' => true
]);
```

```css
<style>
    .test {
        font-family: "Montserrat"
    }
</style>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="test"># test123</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

the text "test123" has always the default font. how can i change this

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled and double check that the full path to the fonts is what you expect it to be. Do a `var_dump($fontDirs);` after you have added your 2 font directories and see what it contains.

Comment: which error reporting ?
i debug the two variables $fontDirs and $fontdata and the variabled and paths are correct

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: this are the default settings of cakephp. its activated

Comment: Try using the custom font name in lowercase.

Comment: ok i solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The font names of the array and the selected default font must used in lowercase. Anyway the other array keys use uppercase in names, the new custom fonts must use lowercase.

```
$fontData = $fontData + [
    'montserrat' => [
        'R' => 'Montserrat-Regular.ttf'
    ],
    'poppins' => [
        'R' => 'Poppins-Regular.ttf'
    ]
];

Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => [
        'className' => 'CakePdf.Mpdf',
        'options' => [
            'fontDir' => $fontDirs,
            'fontdata' => $fontData,
            'default_font_size' => 10,
            'default_font' => 'montserrat'
        ]
    ],
    'margin' => [
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ],
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'download' => true
]);
```